# How to add new menu item to QML(control version 2,1) Menu

Tags: qt, qml

I had just update my QT from 5.6 to 5.8, and I found lots of qml interfaces had changed, like the Menu item.

In 5.6, the addItem method of menu accept a string as parameter.
In 5.8, the same function requires an object.

And how can i construct that object?

The document seems out-date: the local document seems 1.6 and the website seems older, the interfaces they described is obviously not the latest version.

Where can i get the latest version of document for qml? Do I need to pay?

here is the sample code:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Rectangle {
    id:rootRect

    Menu{
        id:menuTest
        y:90
    }
    Rectangle{
        id:testArea1
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                menuTest.close();
                menuTest.x = 0;
                menuTest.addItem({"text":"1234245235"});
                menuTest.open();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `QtQuick.Controls 2` the `Menu` has a structure of

```
Menu {
    MenuItem { text: 'Name0' }
    MenuItem { text: 'Name1' }
    MenuItem { text: 'Name2' }
}
```

If you are looking for the documentation of the `QtQuick.Controls 2`-documentation, look [**here**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html)

In `Qt5.8` you can also still use the `QtQuick.Controls 1` for which you can find the documentation [**here**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html)

To have something as similar to the old `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` you can define yourself a function, that creates the `MenuItem`s for you.

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        menu.addEntry('test')
        menu.open()
    }
}

Menu {
    id: menu
    function addEntry(title) {
        menu.addItem(menuItem.createObject(menu, { text: title }))
    }

    Component {
        id: menuItem
        MenuItem {

        }
    }
}
```

Handeling the signals is also possible, but I don't which way is the most convenient for you. You could pass functions in the addEntry-function, and connect them there to the newly created object, e.g.

Comment: Yes, it's 5.8, I had correct it. But I really want to use the latest version, for there may be bugs and limitations in QtQuick.Controls 1

Comment: @HaozheXie, this is about QtQuick.Controls 2. QtQuick 2 itself has no Menu or MenuItem. Though currently I am not working with Qt anymore, I might be able to help you, if you are more specific, on what is not working, what it is you are trying to achive and how you would expect it to be working. I am positive I tested this code with Qt 5.8+ and QtQuick.Controls 2.x

Comment: Thank you for this answer ... ! Works like charm !